# Change Profession in Passport for Visa Application

Tags: passports, schengen-visas, spain

I'm currently working as a Teaching Assistant in a public university and I'm also working as a part time developer at a software company. My occupation in the passport is "Teaching Assistant". I applied for a master's degree scholarship and got an admission from a private university abroad. The next step is to apply for the schengen visa. the required documents for the visa application include:

- A letter from the workplace indicating the leave date and the leave approval, and in the case of an employee in the government they should provide an official approval on sending them for study.

Getting a leave letter from my public university is hard since I've applied to a private university which is not recognized by my university. So they will not approve my leave (I plan to quit the university in the case of getting the visa). While getting a leave letter from the software company I work for is much easier.

Should I change the occupation in my passport and not mention anything about working for my current university? If I apply with the current profession (with the occupation specified as TA) and with only the leave letter from the company will this harm my application?

**Note** : I'm from Egypt and the private university I applied for is in Spain.

Comment: I feel like you're applying for the wrong visa. How long is the overseas program? Are you applying for a student visa?

Comment: @mkennedy I haven't applied for the visa yet but I think it would be a student visa (the admission letter is expected to be sent soon). The expected duration of the program is 9~12 months. These details will be clarified in details in the invitation letter.

Comment: You're worrying unnecessarily. Unless your profession in the passport is something like **terrorist** you don't have to worry about the difference. Some countries also scrutinize soldiers differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most countries don't put "occupation" in their passports at all.

Given the frequency people change jobs or careers in today's world, I think most western countries would find it completely unreasonable to consider a job change to invalidate someone's passport.

Any "occupation" notation in a passport will be taken as an indication of what the holder's job was *when the passport was issued*, rather than as a commitment to stay in the same job until the passport expires.

Comment: Converted from a comment by request.